# Total reputation count and number of upvotes received mismatch

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I hit a single day reputation of `380` yesterday, but something weird caught my eye. Refer the highlighted answer of the image below, the reputation is counted only for 1 upvote +  acceptance. But the actual answer has 2 upvotes + acceptance.
Why isn't the another upvote not treated as part of the daily-rep?

[image]

The capture image for the actual answer.

[image]

I am aware of the daily rep cap limit and upvotes not treated when the answer added as part of community Wiki, but I haven't done either?

Any reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Rep cap. You have 12 accepts that make 180 then 200 from upvotes.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Am not sure I get it, can you explain it a bit more.  Meaning, I hit my daily limit?